# Not understanding how to add cart into PHP

Tags: php

I am stuck on this code. I am making a web page and on the side there is a place for a cart. And with the you should be able to click on an item and add it to cart. Well I am having trouble getting it to add it to cart. Can someone help me understand what I should be doing. I have been working on it for a few days and no matter what I am doing nothing is working. If i get the code to show you have 0 in your cart it wont add anything if i try to put it in the cart.

```
  <h1>Cart Contents?</h1>
    <div class="p2">
<?php
// Get all the categories and
// link them to category.php.

// Define and execute the query:
$q = 'SELECT category_id, category FROM categories ORDER BY category';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

// Fetch the results:
while (list($fcid, $fcat) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {

    // Print as a list item.
    echo "<li><a href=\"category.php?cid=$fcid\">$fcat</a></li>\n";

    if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']!="CART FILE"){
                echo "<h1>Cart Contents</h1>";
                echo "<div class=\"p2\">";
                $itemCount=X;
                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as X=>X){

                    for($i=0;$i<count(X);$i++){
                        $itemCount+=X;
                      }

                }
                echo "<a href=\"cart.php\">You have ".$itemCount." total items in your cart.</a>";
                echo "</div>\n";


} // End of while loop.

        ?>
        <h1>Specials?</h1>
        <div class="p2">
            <p>Maybe place specials or new items or related items here.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content">
```

Ok here is a link to what the cart should do if you look over to the side it should do what that one is doing.
http://www.programmerskit.com/advPHP/ch5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
        $itemCount=X;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as X=>X){

                for($i=0;$i<count(X);$i++){
                    $itemCount+=X;
                  }

            }
```

just be:

```
$itemCount = count($_SESSION['cart']);
```

I can't otherwise figure out what that code is supposed to be doing.

Also, that code that outputs the cart appears to be in a while loop outputting each item category, so you will be displaying the cart multiple times, which I can only assume is not desired functionality.

Also, another poster made a point about the invalid use of X as a constant, which is also a good point.

Comment: well on my end I am trying to get the cart to go in right to function right. in the cart spot it should say you have 0 items in your cart. Till i go over to the items and want to add them in. After i push the upgrade button to add them it should say something like you have 4 items in your shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bare `X` used all over the place. While saying

```
$somevar = X;
```

would be legitimate if you'd already done `define('X', 'somevalue')` previously, this next one

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as X=>X){
```

is completely invalid. You cannot assign new values to a defined constant, let alone try to assign TWO different values at the same time

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value)
```

is how that particular bit of code should be.

Comment: ok marc this is my first time messing with doing a shopping cart. Now you say you can not assign two different values at the same time. My question would be what values would you put in there. Like 0 or 1,2 i went over my cart.php code to try to help with it but  still aint understanding it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a shopping cart. Your foreach loop is wrong. `X => X` means to make `X = key from the array` and then also `X = value from the array`. So... "take the key & value from the array, and try to shove both values into the constant 'X'". Besides the fact that you can't have a single variable in PHP have two different values, you cannot ASSIGN values to a constant.

Comment: Well I guess I am lost because there is no Arrays in my code at all that I am working on. I have a cart.php and product.php but that is it. I know what I have to do is for it to say if someone added a product to the shopping cart or the cart has 0 in it.

Comment: If there are no arrays, why are you using foreach? That's for looping over the elements of an array. Honestly... go brush up on basic PHP syntax before trying something like this. Regardless of what you're trying to accomplish, the basic PHP syntax in your code is flat out wrong.